# Graphics2D: How to create consistent padding around an irregular shape?

Tags: java, awt, zooming, graphics2d

I'm using Java Graphics2D to generate this map with some sort of tinted red overlay over it. As you can see, the overlay gets cut off along the image boundary on the left side:-

[image]

After demo'ing this to my project stakeholders, what they want is for this overlay to clip along the map boundary with some consistent padding around it. The simple reason for this is to give users the idea that the overlay extends outside the map.

So, my initial thought was to perform a "zoom and shift", by creating another larger map that serves as a "cookie cutter", here's my simplified code:-

```
// polygon of the map
Polygon minnesotaPolygon = ...;

// convert polygon to area
Area minnesotaArea = new Area();
minnesotaArea.add(new Area(minnesotaPolygon));

// this represents the whole image
Area wholeImageArea = new Area(new Rectangle(mapWidth, mapHeight));

// zoom in by 8%
double zoom = 1.08;

// performing "zoom and shift"
Rectangle bound = minnesotaArea.getBounds();
AffineTransform affineTransform = new AffineTransform(g.getTransform());
affineTransform.translate(-((bound.getWidth() * zoom) - bound.getWidth()) / 2,
                          -((bound.getHeight() * zoom) - bound.getHeight()) / 2);
affineTransform.scale(zoom, zoom);
minnesotaArea.transform(affineTransform);

// using it as a cookie cutter
wholeImageArea.subtract(minnesotaArea);

g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
g.fill(wholeImageArea);
```

The reason I'm filling the outside part with green is to allow me to see if the cookie cutter is implemented properly. Here's the result:-

[image]

As you can see, "zoom and shift" doesn't work in this case. There is absolutely no padding at the bottom right. Then, I realized that this technique will not work for irregular shape, like the map... and it only works on simpler shapes like square, circle, etc.

What I want is to create consistent padding/margin around the map before clipping the rest off. To make sure you understand what I'm saying here, I photoshopped this image below (albeit, poorly done) to explain what I'm trying to accomplish here:-

[image]

I'm not sure how to proceed from here, and I hope you guys can give me some guidance on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just explain the logic, as I don't have time to write the code myself. The short answer is that you should step through each pixel of the map image and if **any** pixels in the surrounding area (i.e. a certain distance away) are considered "land" then you register the current pixel as part of the padding area.

For the long answer, here are 9 steps to achieve your goal.

1. Decide on the size of the padding. Let's say 6 pixels.

2. Create an image of the map in monochrome (black is "water", white is "land"). Leave a margin of at least 6 pixels around the edge. This is the input image: (it isn't to scale)

[image: black and white map]

3. Create an image of a circle which is 11 pixels in diameter (11 = 6*2-1). Again, black is empty/transparent, white is solid. This is the hit-area image:

[image: 11 pixel wide circle]

4. Create a third picture which is all black (to start with). Make it the same size as the input image. It will be used as the output image.

5. Iterate each pixel of the input image.

6. At that pixel overlay the hit-area image (only do this virtually, via calculation), so that the center of the hit-area (the white circle) is over the current input image pixel.

7. Now iterate each pixel of the hit-area image.

8. If the any white pixel of the hit-area image intersects a white pixel of the input image then draw a white pixel (where the center of the circle is) into the output image.

9. Go to step 5.

Admittedly, from step 6 onward it isn't so simple, but it should be fairly easy to implement. Hopefully you understand the logic. If my explanation is too confusing (sorry) then I could spend some time and write the full solution (in Javascript, C# or Haskell).